# Mapping RET to use the same indentation level as the previous line

Tags: indentation, newlines, erlang-mode

I code in Erlang, and I dislike the default indentation style that `erlang.el` provides: it tends to push code way too far to the right for my likings.

I'd like to have a simple automatic indentation scheme: (1) pressing RET creates a newline with the same indentation level as the previous line; (2) pressing TAB moves the indentation level one level up.

I figured out (2) by adding `(defalias 'erlang-indent-command 'tab-to-tab-stop)` to my `init.el`, but I can't find a proper command to use for RET to solve (1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
(defun newline-and-indent-same-level ()
  "Insert a newline, then indent to the same column as the current line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((col (save-excursion
               (back-to-indentation)
               (current-column))))
    (newline)
    (indent-to-column col)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `newline-and-indent`:

> newline-and-indent is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.
>
> (newline-and-indent)
>
> Insert a newline, then indent according to major mode.
>   Indentation is done using the value of ‘indent-line-function’.
>   In programming language modes, this is the same as TAB.
>   In some text modes, where TAB inserts a tab, this command indents to the
>   column specified by the function ‘current-left-margin’.