# add a new line with the same indentation level as the current line

Tags: python, indentation

when python code block gets larger, it's hard to find the right indentation level

```
def foo():
    for a in l:  # l1
    # l1-1
        for b in k: # l2
            print(a)
        # (2)
    print(b)
    # (1)
```

suppose I have my cursor at the first `for` (l1 line) , then I would insert a new line at `# (1)` and move cursor there
similarly from `# l2` to `# (2)`

I found similar solution https://superuser.com/q/1017094/309229 but it navigates only, it doesn't let me create a new line.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30363/mapping-ret-to-use-the-same-indentation-level-as-the-previous-line?rq=1?

Comment: @ManuelUberti thanks, but it seems it goes from #l1 to #l1-1 not # (1)

Answer (score 0):

It may be not accepted by usual Python standards. See the picture below
and note the error [E115]. (the `:'
[introduce an indented block](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E115.html))

[image]

This is automatically corrected if you add the `apheleia` package to your
`init.el` and add the Python module `black` to your installation,
which is a code format utility. See the picture below.

[image]

As for indentation guides, the package `highlight-indent-guides` may
help you - the character `?\x2502` draw a tiny vertical line, as in
posted pictures.

```
(use-package highlight-indent-guides
  :defer t
  :hook (prog-mode-hook . highlight-indent-guides-mode)
  :init
  (setq highlight-indent-guides-method 'character
        highlight-indent-guides-character ?\x2502)
  (highlight-indent-guides-mode 1))
```